# Real Analysis: Prove that an is an increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the following is an increasing sequence:

[image]

Here is my attempt at proof by induction:
Prove: $a_n≤4-\frac{2}{n}$ for $n≥1$

Base Case: Prove for $n=1$, Thus we have:
$1≤4-\frac{2}{1}⇒1≤2$

The base case holds true. For the inductive step, we assume that $n = k$ is true:
$k≤4-\frac{2}{k}$ for $k≥1$

Now we seek to prove that $k+1$ is true:

$k+1≤4-\frac{2}{k+1} \Rightarrow k+1≤\frac{4(k+1)-2}{k+1} \Rightarrow k+1≤\frac{4k+2}{k+1}$

$(k+1)^2≤2(k+2)$

not sure the next step.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove $a_n\le 4-\frac{2}{n}$? You are not asked to prove that, you are supposed to take this on faith/assume it is true. Unless you do it for your own curiosity.

Comment: It’s an increasing sequence, because the next term is just like the previous term, but with something positive added onto it

Comment: Even if you were asked to prove that $a_n \le 4-\frac2n$, your induction process seems to be an attempt at proving the statement $n\le 4-\frac2n$ because, for $n=1$, you have written $n=1\le 4-\frac21=4-\frac2n$, which though true for $n=1$ is not true for $n\ge 4$ obviously.

Comment: I need to prove that the sequence is increasing. Therefore for all of n, k(n)<k(n+1)

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_1=2>0$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac 2{(n+1)^2}$ for $n\geqslant 1$. Since $\frac 2{n^2}>0$ for all $n$, it is clear that $a_{n+1}>a_n$, and so by induction we conclude that $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence.

Given that $a_n\leqslant 4-\frac2n$ for all $n$, we can conclude that the sequence converges, as an increasing sequence with an upper bound converges to its least upper bound.